# MySQL proc weird output

Tags: mysql, procedure

I am trying to create something on the columns of one of my tables. I created a mysql proc which comes with weird output. The proc:

```
create procedure test (
   in in_database varchar(255),
   in in_table varchar(255))
begin
   declare done            int default false;
   declare stmt            text default '';
   declare var_column_name varchar(64);
   declare var_data_type   varchar(64);

   declare
      cur_cols cursor
   for
      select
         column_name,data_type
      from
         information_schema.columns 
      where
         table_schema = in_database collate utf8_general_ci 
      and
         table_name = in_table collate utf8_general_ci
      order  by
         ordinal_position asc;

   set done = false;

   open cur_cols;
   colsloop: loop
      fetch cur_cols
      into
         var_column_name,
         var_data_type;

      if done then
         leave colsloop;
      end if;

      set stmt = concat(ifnull(stmt,''),':',ifnull(var_column_name,''));

   end loop;
   close cur_cols;

   select stmt;

end$$
```

Pretty straight-forward: adding column-names to a variable and when done outputting the result to the console. When I test-run my procedure like this:

```
call test('mysql','columns_priv');
```

I get

```
Error Code: 1329 (02000): No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed
```

when I move the final select statement into the loop, I can see the stmt variable building up, but still ending in the 1329 error message.

I have tried COALESCE instead of IFNULL, explicitly setting variable stmt to '', but I keep getting this strange output, also on . I thought I build this little utility proc in half an hour, but it has cost me already half a day and I don't know what is going wrong.

Unfortunately, the database hosting the proc has a different collation, hence the COLLATE. Other than that I don't see why this code won't run.

Any pointers are very welcome.

Comment: Why not just select the column names using GROUP_CONCAT and group on the table_schema? You can set the delimiter to ":" and end up with the same output with only one select statement.

Answer (score 0):

You might try a query similar to the following. It gets a list like your script, but without the looping.

```
SELECT 
    `TABLE_NAME`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `COLUMN_NAME` ORDER BY `ORDINAL_POSITION` SEPARATOR ':') as `column_list`
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE `TABLE_NAME` like '%assets%'
GROUP BY `TABLE_NAME`
```

Comment: Thanks Sloan, that is an interesting thought, but I primarily want to understand why my code doesn't run. Also, a lot more must be done in the proc than just listing all columns separated by semicolons. This is just a first sample, but even this code doesn't run.To be more precise: what exactly is producing the 1329?